# T-SQL Procedure Custom RAISERROR Always Shows As Number 18054 In VS2010 When Using EF4

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, exception

I have a stored procedure on a hosted SQL 2008 instance. In these stored procedures is logic checking for error. I then return an error code using `RAISERROR(#####, ##, ###)` if there is a problem. This works well enough, but there is a problem with catching such an error.

In Visual Studio 2010 I can catch the error with the correct `Class` and `State`, but never the correct `Number`. I will get a `Message` like the following in the exception:

`Error #####, severity ##, state ###, was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.message. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.`

So clearly the error is being raised correctly from the procedure, but the `Number` returned is always 18054. What am I doing wrong? I don't care what the text of the message is, and I don't have permission to run `sp_addmessage` anyway. However, I would like `Number` to be correct so I can properly catch the error in my application and handle it properly.

In case it matters, I'm calling the procedure using EF4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your* error *isn't* being raised correctly. The error you're actually getting, 18054, is a system error which pretty much says,

> "Hey, you called raiserror() with an error number which doesn't appear in [sys].[messages]!"

If you don't have access to add records to `[sys].[messages]` just specify your error number in the message text ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)):

```
RAISERROR (N'321433', -- Message text. Parse as int in exception handling.
           10, -- Severity
           1) -- State
```

Comment: But how do I catch an error messsage reliably? Catching an error ID or Number is so much easier. Otherwise I'm left matching strings. Suggestions?

Comment: Have your dba add it to `sys.messages` via `sp_addmessage`... or just put the error number in your message text and parse it as an int in your exception handler.

Comment: Unfortunately `sp_addmessage` requires both `sysadmin` and `serveradmin` fixed server roles. That is impossible in a shared hosting environment. And trying to insert directly in to `sys.messages` results in error 259 "Add hoc updates to system catalogs are not allowed." I guess I'll just return a number as a string and match that. Thanks.